# Association mapping with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have two Entities:

User and
Comment

Every comment can only have one user but a user can have multiple comments.

I'm not sure if I want to use biderectional, Unidirectional with Join Table, or Self-referencing.

I only want this relationship to apply when calling the comment object. If I call a user object somewhere I do not want a bunch of comment objects flooding the user object. Which approach should I take?

Comment: Use a many to one unidirectional relationship within the comment object

Comment: This is moot, you won't get a bunch of comment objects unless you specifically call User->getComments() or use a repository method where you join and specifically request comments be hydrated. Symfony/Doctrine will always lazy load associations by default with the caveat of one to one relationships which will always eager load (in 2.3 at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony's documentation explains the process pretty well : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects

> What's important is the fact that you have easy access to the
>   product's related category, but the category data isn't actually
>   retrieved until you ask for the category (i.e. it's "lazily loaded").

Just make a ManyToOne relationship, and only fetch a user's comments when you need to.

`User` entity:

```
<?php
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="author")
     */
    protected $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

`Comment` entity:

```
<?php
class Comment
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $author;
}
```